# Is Amazon DocDB aggregate sorting dfiferent from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aggregation

So, if I understand the aggregation pipeline correctly, then each action in the pipeline is executed on the documents that the previous action 'generated'.

So, currently we are in the way of migrating from own hosted Mongo to AWS hosted DocDB. Now there are some difference which I read about [beforehand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html) from Amazons documentation. But I don't think this one was in there, so maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

So, I add these documents to my collection called `interactions`

```
db.interactions.insert([
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5daf0eb72f60b87bb2df4579"),
    "meta_data" : {
        "behavior_id" : "52f46df7ce882cd1888f9123",
        "activity_id" : "576437f8feb8bcf4a08df23c",
    },
    "created_at" : 2,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5daf0eb72f60b87bb2df457a"),
    "meta_data" : {
        "behavior_id" : "56c7914bbc1b9c03001bc11a",
        "activity_id" : "576437f8feb8bcf4a08df23b",
    },
    "created_at" : 1,
}
])
```

If I then just do this:

```
db.interactions.aggregate([

    {$match: {}},
    {$sort: { created_at: -1 }},

])
```

On both DocDb and Mongo I get the same output in the order I expect (and changing the sort number to 1 flips the results)

(Eg I just get what I have in the collection, but descended sorted on created at).

But if I now add the following group pipe (which I assume is now done against my sorted documents).

```
{$group: { "_id": "$meta_data.behavior_id",  "activity_id": {$last: "$meta_data.activity_id"}}}
```

On mongo I get this:

```
{ "_id" : "56c7914bbc1b9c03001bc11a", "activity_id" : "576437f8feb8bcf4a08df23b" }
{ "_id" : "52f46df7ce882cd1888f9123", "activity_id" : "576437f8feb8bcf4a08df23c" }
```

Which seems to be the correct order and changing the order number to 1 also affects this result. But on DocDB I always get:

```
{ "_id" : "52f46df7ce882cd1888f9123", "activity_id" : "576437f8feb8bcf4a08df23c" }
{ "_id" : "56c7914bbc1b9c03001bc11a", "activity_id" : "576437f8feb8bcf4a08df23b" }
```

And changing the order does not do anything anymore.

Is this just something that doesn't work the same on DocDBB or am I just expecting something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on MongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ it is stated that `$group does not order its output documents.`

Even in the example they provide they `$sort` it as the last part of the aggregation.

I found similar issue here: [Sort and Group in one MongoDB aggregation query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278962/sort-and-group-in-one-mongodb-aggregation-query)